# Does the Azure Search individual query clause limit apply to a `search.in` filter clause?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'd like to use Azure Search's `search.in` filter clause to do security trimming. I'm expecting to need to pass up to 10,000 ids to the clause (not usually, but sometimes).

The azure search documentation states that an individual query clause is limited to 32kb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_querysizelimits

I was worried about hitting that limit, so I did a spike with a large (100,000 item) `search.in` query and it seem to work absolutely fine.

But I'm worried I'm going against what the documentation appears to advise. [While the documentation does say that a filter with a search.in is ideal for security trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#filter-operators), does it seem like i'm safe to use search.in with large sets of ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32 KB limit is for terms in full Lucene queries, and does not apply to filters (except when mixing Lucene queries with filters via `search.ismatch` or `search.ismatchscoring`). We specifically designed `search.in` to handle scenarios like yours.

Please see [Security Trimming in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search) for more information.

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search for more information

Comment: Thanks @MatthewGotteiner, I've added this to the answer.